# How to separate code (specifically JS) into "terms" for use with TF-IDF

Tags: javascript, tf-idf, information-retrieval

I am looking to implement TF-IDF*) on some files, however, they are JS files and I am unsure of how exactly to break up a JS file by term. With regular text it is generally pretty straight-forward as you can use words. Just seperated by spaces. However this seems like something that is not as straight-forward when working with code, as 'terms' could be separated by any number of characters.

I would like to use it to search for and find instances of plagiarism across many code bases, and compare them for how similar they are. Comments I think would be important for identifying similar/same files.

Is there some standard way of doing this? Or does anybody have any ideas on how to separate code into terms for use with TF-IDF?

*)

> TF-IDF (term frequency-inverse document frequency) is a statistical measure that evaluates how relevant a word is to a document in a collection of documents. This is done by multiplying two metrics: how many times a word appears in a document, and the inverse document frequency of the word across a set of documents.

Comment: Would you be OK with defining a term as being a lexeme?

Comment: @Vivick Yes, I think a lexeme would be the closest thing to a term in this case.

Comment: @mplungjan The meaning or functionality of the code is not particularly important for my use case. I would like to use it to search for and find instances of plagiarism across many code bases, and compare them for how similar they are. Comments I think would be important for identifying similar/same files.

Comment: @mplungjan As for JS keywords, they could be removed, but it is my understanding that TF-IDF accounts for terms that are used across every document and lowers their score.

Comment: @LeeMorgan I updated your question with the aim since that is important to the granularity of the evaluation